# Literal values in value constructor

Tags: haskell

I have a data type called Event. It looks like this:

```
data Event = Event { tag :: String
                   , description :: String
                   , date :: String
                   } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I want to make a special kind of Event that would always have a fallback value in the `tag` and `date` fields. Basically, I would like to write something like this (please excuse the incorrect syntax):

```
data GeneralEvent =       Event String String String
                  | FaultyEvent "unknown-tag" String "unknown-date"
```

Using record syntax for defining `FaultyEvent` also doesn't seem to offer a solution either (again, please excuse the incorrect syntax): :

```
data FaultyEvent = FaultyEvent { "unknown-tag" :: String
                               , description :: String
                               , date :: String
                               } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Is there a nice way of creating a special kind of `Event` in Haskell? Or are my syntactical problems caused by not thinking in the proper Haskell way?

Comment: Define a function that builds your special events.

Comment: To echo n.m.'s comment, this should be of interest: https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors

Comment: What you want cannot be done. However you may be interested in [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors)

Comment: Thanks, smart constructors look like a good solution. Reid's answer offers the other standard approach, smart destructors, and I am inclined to accept that as it is the only answer offered. And smart destructors don't seem to require one to hide the constructors (and give up on pattern-matching).

Answer (score 3):

You can just let your type represent the data you have, and put the logic in "smart destructors", i.e., functions. Try

```
data Event = Event String String String
           | FaultyEvent String

tag :: Event -> String
tag (Event t _ _) = t
tag FaultyEvent = "unknown-tag"

-- etc.
```

Of course you are not restricted to `tag :: Event -> String`, you could define `tag :: Event -> Maybe String` instead if it's more useful, without changing the definition of Event.